# Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. Website Loop

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a website that allows you to pull json files and compare them in a graph. However, as soon as the site is opened, I receive this error in the Chrome console, in a loop.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Alert from '@mui/material/Alert';

const API = ({ dashboards, setData, selectedOption2 }) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchJSONData = async () => {
      try {
        const combinedData = [];
        for (const dashboard of dashboards) {
          const url = ****
          const response = await axios.get(url);
          const rawData = Array.isArray(response.data) ? response.data : [response.data];
          const formattedData = rawData.map((item) => ({
            'Electric Field': item.electric_field,
            'Drift Velocity': item.electron_drift_velocity,
            'Diffusion Coefficient': item.electron_longitudinal_diffusion,
            'Transversal Diffusion': item.electron_transversal_diffusion,
            'Pressure': item.pressure,
          }));
```

This is the starting part of my code. I assign the data it captures to a variable and use it in another file.

```
        setData(combinedData);
        setError(null);
      } catch (error) {
        setError('An error occurred while fetching data: "Data does not exist."');
        setData([]);
      }
    };
    fetchJSONData();
  }, [dashboards, selectedOption2 ,setData ]);
```

here is the part where I assign the variable and define the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The error might have occurred because of the way you are using the setData function inside the loop. With this React will trigger a re-render of the component and since you were calling it inside the loop, it created an infinite loop of state updates and re-renders.

```js
for (const dashboard of dashboards) {
  // ... fetch and format data ...

  setData(combinedData);
}
```

Instead you can push each object in a iteration and set the data after loop.

```js
 for (const dashboard of dashboards) {
      // ... fetch and format data ...
      combinedData.push(...formattedData); // Accumulate data
    }
    setData(combinedData); // Set the accumulated data
```

Comment: i try do change but its didn't work for me. You can check my all code in here : https://github.com/Alperenkarslix/gas-graphs/blob/main/src/api/api.js